# Correct HttpStatusCode to Return for an Upsert Operation in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-status-codes

When doing a POST in ASP.NET Web API, I generally return a 201 (Created) for a successfully created resource. I'm working on a POST that performs an upsert on the back end; am wondering if there's any standard or "correct" HttpStatusCode for this scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will usually depend on the scenario. For example: what should the query return if there are more than one items or if authorisation is required? 
Interesting to see what others do e.g. [Salesforce](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_upsert.htm)  ( btw I am not affiliated with SF in any way)